# Locating multiple files in large dataset in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I have a large repository of image files (~2 million, `.jpg`) with individual ids spread in multiple sub-dirs and I'm trying to locate and copy each image on a list containing a ~1,000 subset of these ids.

I'm still very new to Python so my first thought was to use `os.walk` to iterate through the 1k subset for each file, to see if any within the subset matched the id. This works, at least theoretically, but it seems incredibly slow at something like 3-5 images a second. The same seems to be the case for running through all of the files looking for one id at a time.

```py
import shutil
import os
import csv

# Wander to Folder, Identify Files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ImgFolder):
    for file in files:
        fileName = ImgFolder + str(file)
# For each file, check dictionary for match
        with open(DictFolder, 'r') as data1:
            csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(data1)
            for row in csv.DictReader(data1):
                img_id_line = row['id_line']
                isIdentified = (img_id_line in fileName) and ('.jpg' in fileName)
# If id_line == file ID, copy file
                if isIdentified:
                    src = fileName + '.jpg'
                    dst = dstFolder + '.jpg'
                    shutil.copyfile(src,dst)
                else:
                    continue
```

I've been looking at trying to automate query searches instead, but the data is contained on a NAS and I have no easy way of indexing the files to make querying faster. The machine I'm running the code through is a W10 and thus I can't use the Ubuntu Find method which I gather is considerably better at this task.

Any way to speed up the process would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you'll need to leverage multiprocessing to speed this up

Comment: to add on to what @gold_cy said, it would probably be beneficial to build some sort of index to speed up future searches

Comment: You should create an index/lookup of all the files that you can query

Comment: @Alex I appreciate that indexing would speed up the process, but afaik, that would require admin access to the drive which I sadly have no way of obtaining

Comment: How are you planning to copy the files if you don't have permission to determine their locations?

Comment: @Alex perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean by indexing (?) but I'm working (remotely) through a university computer. While I do have permission to download, copy, edit files etc, I do not have access to control-panel-level features such as advanced indexing which requires admin.

Comment: So how does the code you're running access the remote files?

Comment: @Alex (again, apologies if I am misunderstanding some basic concept)

I am able to run my code as if the drive containing the data is local as it is located on a nas drive. That said, the machine to which I have 'attached' the nas is university-owned and as such I can't access admin. I also don't think W10 is capable of indexing anything that isn't local file storage. The data itself is too large for a local storage drive.

Comment: You can create your own index of the files on the NAS, that is what I am suggesting. This is only really necessary if you're going to want to find arbitrary files again and again. What isn't clear from your question is what is `'id_line'` is this the filename (`some_file.jpg`) or the stem (`some_file`)? Are all the image filenames unique?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235884/discussion-between-corpa-and-alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of scripts that should do what you're looking for.

*`index.py`*

This script uses [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to walk through directories searching for files with a given extension. It will write a TSV file with two columns, filename and filepath.

```py
import argparse
from pathlib import Path


def main(args):
    for arg, val in vars(args).items():
        print(f"{arg} = {val}")

    ext = "*." + args.ext
    index = {}
    with open(args.output, "w") as fh:
        for file in Path(args.input).rglob(ext):
            index[file.name] = file.resolve()
            fh.write(f"{file.name}\t{file.resolve()}\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument(
        "input",
        help="Top level folder which will be recursively "
        " searched for files ending with the value "
        "provided to `--ext`",
    )
    p.add_argument("output", help="Output file name for the index tsv file")
    p.add_argument(
        "--ext",
        default="jpg",
        help="Extension to search for. Don't include `*` or `.`",
    )
    main(p.parse_args())
```

*`search.py`*

This script will load the index (output from `index.py`) into a dicttionary, then it will load the CSV file into a dictionary, then for each `id_line` it will look for the filename in the index and attempt to copy it to the output folder.

```py
import argparse
import csv
import shutil
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path


def main(args):
    for arg, val in vars(args).items():
        print(f"{arg} = {val}")

    if not Path(args.dest).is_dir():
        Path(args.dest).mkdir(parents=True)

    with open(args.index) as fh:
        index = dict(l.strip().split("\t", 1) for l in fh)
    print(f"Loaded {len(index):,} records")

    csv_dict = defaultdict(list)

    with open(args.csv) as fh:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
        for row in reader:
            for (k, v) in row.items():
                csv_dict[k].append(v)

    print(f"Searching for {len(csv_dict['id_line']):,} files")
    copied = 0
    for file in csv_dict["id_line"]:
        if file in index:
            shutil.copy2(index[file], args.dest)
            copied += 1
        else:
            print(f"!! File {file!r} not found in index")
    print(f"Copied {copied} files to {args.dest}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument("index", help="Index file from `index.py`")
    p.add_argument("csv", help="CSV file with target filenames")
    p.add_argument("dest", help="Target folder to copy files to")
    main(p.parse_args())
```

##### How to run this:

```sh
python index.py --ext "jpg" "C:\path\to\image\folder" "index.tsv"
python search.py "index.tsv" "targets.csv" "C:\path\to\output\folder"
```

I would try this on one/two folders first to check that it has the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that file names are unique and files location doesn't change, it is possible to create a dictionary that will allow searching for a file path in **O(1) time complexity**. The dictionary creation process will take some time, it is possible to [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) it on your computer, so you have to run it only once.

A simple script to create the dictionary:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pickle


root = Path('path/to/root/folder')
# files extensions to index
extensions = {'.jpg', '.png'}
# iterating over whole `root` directory tree and indexing by file name
image = {file.stem: file for file in root.rglob('*.*') if file.suffix in extensions}
# saving the index on your computer for further use
index_path = Path('path/to/index.pickle')
with index_path.open('wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(image, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

An example of loading the dictionary:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pickle


index_path = Path('path/to/index.pickle')
with index_path.open('rb') as file:
    image = pickle.load(file)
```