# Speed up python code os.walk() glob file lookup

Tags: python, performance, os.walk

I have python code that looks at a directory, and finds all the files that match a pattern. This folder has about 6TB of data, thousands of subfolders and about 450,000 files. The computer has a powerful intel xeon cpu, and this folder is on a network drive which seems a little slow. Running this can take an hour sometimes. Is there any way to speed this process up? There are usually less than 100 files that I am looking for out of 450k.

```
pattern = "*20210929.hdf5"
files=[]

for dir,_,_ in os.walk(directory):
    files.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(dir,pattern)))
```

Comment: Finding files by name is almost exclusively bound by filesystem metadata performance. Everything but optimising the "network drive which seems a little slow" will likely be a waste of effort.

Comment: Note that you can *shorten* the code using ``**`` globs, e.g. as ``*files = pathlib.Path(directory).glob('**/' + pattern)``. This won't speed up the operation, though.

Comment: multiprocessing can decrease the time it runs by dividing the subfolder searching amongst the different workers

Comment: In addition to MisterMiyagi's reply, a good strategy if you are unable to speed up the networked computer is to create an file with all the paths that you can search instead of re-querying the remote computer every time.

Comment: There are some strategies here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68743246/3279716

Comment: @gold_cy Unless the filesystem is built explicitly for concurrent operations, concurrent searches will most likely trash the metadata cache. If metadata operations are the bottleneck to begin with, this will make things worse.

Comment: I've had cases where concurrent searches were useful, but those were places where I had extremely-parallel hardware and a FUSE-based filesystem that was poorly written. Spreading out the context switches involved in using that filesystem across more cores improved throughput in that specific case, but it's no general solution.

Comment: BTW, the "make a list of files ahead-of-time and just search that list" approach is what `locate` does, and why it's so very much faster than `find`.

Comment: Thanks for he replies, I run this program daily and it looks for files that were created yesterday, so these are always new files. Does this change things, if I have some index file as Alex mentioned these new files wouldn't be listed on there?

Comment: It's worth quoting from the documentation:- "Using the "\*\*" pattern in large directory trees may consume an inordinate amount of time". It might be worthwhile considering a multithreaded approach. Start with *os.walk()* to identify all possible directories in the directory hierarchy then execute a discrete thread to *glob* just that directory. Having said that, if your NAS is slow then this is just going to put it under even more stress

Comment: Using a remote SSD rather than a remote HDD may help a lot. Moreover, if you have access to the remote machine, you can execute the script remotely rather than sending many commands.